# Estimate of total public expenditure from governments around world?

Tags: government, spending

I [found in Twitter](https://twitter.com/jwyg/status/438010080420585472) a great question related to Open Data SE. Maybe someone knows anything more.

> Does anyone know of an estimate of total public expenditure from governments around world?

Answer (score 4):

This question is hard to answer. There is no database providing a single figure. However, there are some international databases which provide the information for individual countries.

If you want a good coverage of countries, try the [Worldbank's Public Sector Statistics](http://data.worldbank.org/topic/public-sector). Scroll down a bit and click on the [Databank Button](http://databank.worldbank.org/data/table/source/2?Topic=13). For some countries the data is missing. Either they don't have this kind of information or they don't want to share it with the public.

Eurostat has quite complete and good quality [data on government expenses](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/government-finance-statistics/data/database). But obviously, you will be mostly limited to the EU.

The OECD has a wider geographic coverage. On their [statistics site](http://stats.oecd.org/), you will find the data in the "National Accounts" Section:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is the type of question that [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com) is really handy for.

Enter "[total government expenditure](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=total+government+expenditure)" in the input box, and see the results. The results also provide the information sources used.

Edit:

[image]

Comment: You may include a screenshot from the wolfram results, just to improve the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Individually, you could use the [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/).

Under 'economy' there's 'budget' and then 'expenditures'.

I don't know if there's an API for searching it, but I believe that Wikipedia sucked it all out to populate their initial country entries.  (but I don't know the schedule that they've been updated, or if it's consistent)

Comment: That's a pain in the ass if you have to extract this information for each country. Not very useful

Comment: And it is indeed a black box: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/source-of-cia-world-factbook-estimates

Answer (score 2):

Adding to previous good answer, I think that you might find useful the following WDI indicators (http://data.worldbank.org/products/wdi):

- General government final consumption expenditure (current US$): http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NE.CON.GOVT.CD
- General government final consumption expenditure (current LCU): http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NE.CON.GOVT.CN
- Central government debt, total (% of GDP): http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GC.DOD.TOTL.GD.ZS
- Central government debt, total (current LCU): http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GC.DOD.TOTL.CN
- GDP (current US$): http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD

Comment: @HelloWorld: I am not repeating anything. In contrast with user1702's answer, in my answer I'm _clarifying_ information by **suggesting** several **particular indicators** out of hundreds. Does it qualify for being **"useful"**? In case of user974731, your comment is ridiculous, because: 1) that answer has **nothing in common** with mine; 2) even it would, my answer has been posted 16 hours **earlier**!